requireTextDoesNotMatchPattern to prevent duplicate in google form
i need to prevent people to choose the numbers previously chosen. i wrote this script but doesn't work. var data is the column of all number previously chosen.
function uniqueresp() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId)
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('elenco')
 var form = FormApp.openById(formId)

 var data = [...new Set(sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues().map(row=> row[1]))].join('|')
 var item = form.getItems().filter(item=>item.getTitle() == 'Inserire Numero Pilota')[0].asTextItem()
 var pattern =  ` (${data}) ` 
 var textval = FormApp.createTextValidation().setHelpText("Numero non disponibile. Sceglierne un altro").requireTextDoesNotMatchPattern(pattern).build()
   item.setValidation(textval)

i tried to use requireTextMatchesPattern but all numbers trigger the error

Can I ask you about the details of but doesn't work and i tried to use requireTextMatchesPattern but all numbers trigger the error?

@Iamblichus has solved this problem in Allowing only one answer in Google forms.
In short, the number pattern should

include the caret symbol, integer and $ sign, and
exclude opening and closing brackets

Format

This=> ^1$|^5$|^10$|^15$|^20$|^25$|^30$|^35$|^40$|^45$|^50$
Not this=> (1|5|10|15|20|25|30|35|40|45|50)


Substitute these lines of code:
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues().map(row=> row[1]).map(number => `^${number}\$`).join("|");
  var item = form.getItems().filter(item=>item.getTitle() == 'Inserire Numero Pilota')[0].asTextItem()
  var textval = FormApp.createTextValidation()
                .setHelpText("Numero non disponibile. Sceglierne un altro")
                .requireTextDoesNotMatchPattern(data)
                .build()
  item.setValidation(textval)


VALIDATION SNAPSHOT


REJECT EXISTING VALUE

